# Facebook Open Graph like button is taking link instead of article

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a website, on which I have Facebook like button. Now, problem is, that I have open graph meta tags; og: type set to Article, but when someone likes and posts my link, Facebook takes it like LINK and NOT article as it should. 
For ex.:
John Doe likes link bla bla bla.

But it must be like this:

John Doe likes article bla bla bla.

I tried Open Graph debugger, which takes right type. So I don't know where is the problem now. I have enabled and connected my Facebook app with website.

[Here is link to Debugger.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://getthewordout81.com/sandbox/25235)

Answer (score 0):

To get that functionality you have to create an Open Graph action (Like) and use that instead of a regular Like button.

Answer (score 0):

i have a video site ->www.wootube.woolei.com , when people like my page using facebook plugin. It will show like a **Video** instead of link.

can you show us your site instead?we would like to check on your og property.

Regards,
Woolei -> Facebook Application Consultant at woolei.com